# Linux crontab what is the meaning of the line below?

Tags: cron, cron-task

**i have a crontab line and i want to ask some expert what this line will do**

> 10,40 * * * * sh /etc/test/script.sh

please tell me what will 10,40 do in this crontab -e file.i am new to crontab use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*  *  *  *  *  command
-  -  -  -  -
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday = 0)
|  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
|  |  +--------- day (1 - 31)
|  +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

each position takes a comma-separated list of values.

this will execute `sh /etc/test/script.sh` at :10 and :40 every hour.
*00:10, 00:40, 01:10, 01:40, ...*

**additionally**

you can use / to specify an interval, i.e.

```
*/5 * * * * sh /etc/test/script.sh
```

to run it every 5 minutes.

[wikipedia cron page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Configuration_file)

Comment: what if i want to run this after every 5 minutes of every hour
will it be like this 
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60 * * * * sh /etc/test/script.sh

Comment: use */5 in the first column ...

i.e. 
    */5 * * * * sh /etc/test/script.sh

Comment: please accept the answer if it has answered your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: but it would be 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 in your example